# Cannot VNC to KVM Guest

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, vncviewer

I am trying to install Ubuntu desktop in a KVM guest on my Ubuntu server host. Both version 14.04 and 64-bit.

I got through the virt-install ok

```
sudo virt-install -n desktop -r 1024 --disk path=/dev/ubuntu-vg/desktop,bus=virtio,size=40 -c ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso --network network=default,model=virtio --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole -v
```

And have verified the KVM is running. I can see on the host that port 5900 is listening but my VNC connection quickly fails with no error message. I have the ssh tunnel setup right (using putty) and I can see the packets on the Ubuntu host's lo interface. Currently have ufw service stopped.

From tcpdump it looks like the connection runs fine but then the Ubuntu server host sends a reset packet. No clues from the VNC log (running from a Windows Vista client, non-installed version of RealVNC).

Any thoughts on why VNC fails so quickly? Maybe there is another way to connect the this KVM guest and continue the install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I had to turn the colors in the VNC client down to 64 and now it stays connected to the server. This was for the default network settings (no inbound connections to guests).

I changed my KVM install to connect guests to a bridged network and now VNC works fine with more colors.