# Why can color setting affect VNC connection?

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

By following the post [Cannot VNC to KVM Guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598118/cannot-vnc-to-kvm-guest/598125#598125?newreg=13a2c9a99e6e4923ba60971a83908e01), I managed to connect to my guest VM through VNC. But, it's just weird that color setting can lead to an unexpected close of VNC connections. I would like to know the reason. To me, it just is seemed like a BUG since when the color setting is not suitable, it just closes the connection without saying the reason.